# IBM Cloud Foundry and Blockchain: Encountering "Failed to make TCP connection to port 3000: connection refused" when doing cf start

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Our team is currently doing a proof of concept on Hyperledger which uses IBM Cloud Blockchain template and Cloud Foundry. We deployed our Hyperledger blockchain to https://console.bluemix.net/. We are running on Fabric 1.1 and we just followed this tutorial https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-blockchain-starter-plan-network/index.htm to deploy our network.

We are currently encountering the following error after running the following command "cf start ": **ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 3000: connection refused ERR Timed out after 5m0s: health check never passed.**

I've already set the health check timeout to 300 but still no luck. I've also checked the port 3000 it is already allowed / opened. Can someone help me with this issue? If you need more information just let me know and I'll try to provide it as much as I can. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apart for asking the question here, you could also raise a ticket with the IBM Cloud system.

Comment: @RThatcher I've already done that and haven't receive any response from them yet its been like 72 hrs already

Comment: I assume this is an 'official' ticket for IBM Cloud (Bluemix).  I would suggest making sure that the ticket clearly states Blockchain and Starter Plan - and I think there is a tag to use "starter11beta".

Comment: IBM Cloud cases are responded to as quickly as possible based on the account type and severity. Here is an explanation of the IBM Cloud Support response times: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/get-support/ticketweight.html#support-ticket-severity

Comment: @RThatcher already tried it but till now no response from IBM support

Comment: @William'Bill'Wentworth I've just checked and for my current account type the response time stated for it was "no response times needed and when able"